# How do I call properties of objects passed as method arguments when the parameter is a template

Tags: c#, templates, methods

**the following is the class whose object's property I want to access through template method**

```
Public class Construction{
    public int Id;
}
```

**The following is the method whose parameter is a template**

```
public void Delete<T>(T obj){}
```

**Please how do I access the Id property from inside method delete if I pass in a construction object**

Answer (score 1):

You could use an interface.

```
public interface IId
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
public class Construction : IId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public void Delete(IId obj)
{
    var x = obj.Id;
}
```

You could use a constraint, please see [Constraints on type parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).

```
public void Delete2<T>(T obj) where T : Construction
{
   var x = obj.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `System.Reflection`

```
public void Delete<T>(T obj)
{
    if (obj.GetType().Name == "Construction")
    {
        FieldInfo info = obj.GetType().GetField("Id");
        int id = (int)info.GetValue(obj);
    }
}
```